# C++ Template: are all instantiation done in compilation time?

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to define a template with class name T, then use it by sending an parameter where its type could not be defined during compilation time, so that the instantiation only happens in runtime?

Comment: _"then use it by sending an parameter where its type could not be defined during compilation time"_ Could you show a working code sample for that?

Comment: I couldn't so am asking...

Comment: So that's your answer,: You can't.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ man, I can't , but I wonder if anyone can, cause I only have half a brain

Comment: Types have to be known at compile-time. Dynamic types created at run-time do not exist in C++. To create instances of different classes chosen at run-time, you need to use a factory pattern.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thank you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau got it , thank you.